# Calling a console from another and passing parameters in string [] args?

Tags: c#

I need to call a console program from another (an azure worker role) and also pass parameters to use inside this new console.

Like :

Console1:

> var proc = Process.Start("Console2");

Is there something like : proc.parameters or Start("Console2",myParameters) ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty much what you said:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

> Process.Start Method (String, String)
>   Starts a process resource by specifying the name of an application and
>   a set of command-line arguments, and associates the resource with a
>   new Process component.